# How do I fix my selections being invisible in Edit mode?

Tags: selection-tools

I'm following the [Donut tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD) and, I don't know what I have pressed, but out of a sudden, all my selections on Edit Mode are invisible (Vertex, Edge and Face). Selection works and I can modify stuff, but I can't see what I have selected.

In the screenshot you can see me extruding a face, but you can't see that the face is selected. In Object Mode, selection is fine.

Any idea of how to fix that

[image]

EDIT:

Full screen screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot of my overlays:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you kindly attach a screenshot of your whole blender tab? So we can know what settings you might have changed by accident.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I appreciate your reply. I added a screenshot of the whole screen because I didn't know exactly what you meant :)

Comment: Check the last edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have switched overlays off. Enable them to make them visible again:[image]

It looks like you have faces disabled:[image]

Edit: Also check If you disabled something in that dropdown with the arrow and eye:[image]

Comment: Thanks! We are close! I was able to show the coordinates of the face selected, but not the default view (dots around the face). Would you kindly see my last screenshot and guide me on how to enable the default outline for the selected face?

Comment: @AndréPena check my edits.

Comment: I'm sorry but enabling it didn't change it... =(. Check my last edit

Comment: @AndréPena check my last edit.

Comment: I actually got to the solution and posted an answer. I +1d your answer to thank you for the time you spent. That is really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the Solidify modifier is being applied and the "realtime" option is selected, the face gets invisible in Edit Mode.

I think the reason is because that faces doesn't REALLY exist. It's a virtual face created by the modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah... Well, I guess I couldn't find that out since I didn't know that you had modifiers applied. Anyways, at least you're back in business (!

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I'm sorry. I'm so noob that I don't know what matters. But I really do appreciate your time. All the best!

Comment: No problem, experience comes with time! Have fun ;)